# Windows 10 install jekyll error,how can i do?

Tags: jekyll

ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
jekyll-sass-converter requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0.

i have ruby 2.3.3    and  Devkit mingw64 4.7.2

Comment: Which version of jekyll you want to install? Do you want  to install jekyll native, inside WSL or as a Docker

Comment: i dont know what is the difference . i just  building a github page blog by following someone's guild. i have tried a lot  of times,

Comment: Have you tried installing a version of ruby >= 2.4 ?